# Active Admin before_validation hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-resources

I have an Active Admin model, :gallery, and it has a nested paperclip resource, :images. :gallery has_many :images.

:gallery has a field, :title, which is required.

When I submit *without* a title, the other fields persist (:description, :location) but the nested resource becomes blank.

Is there a way to build the resource before validating so it persists after a failed validation check?

```
f.inputs "Images" do 
      f.has_many :images do |i| 

          i.input :image,
                :as=>:file,
                :multipart => true, 
                :label => "Image" 
              end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you added these required things in **Gallery** model

```
 attr_accessible :images_attributes
```

and

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => :true
```

Comment: No joy, those are in place but the form field does not persist if the form fails validation

Comment: @MildFuzz It will be helpful for us if you provide more detailed code from controller side and from view side because I think you don't need hook for that. Rails takes care for nested form if you added code properly.

Comment: I have added the image part of the form. I am not sure how much else is useful.